# Why am I getting Promise instead of a value?

Tags: javascript, promise

I think I do not understand, why am I getting `Promise` in return? I need to create object. Both options to return a value from promise do not work.

Why is it so? What am I missing?

Solution: create variable inside `t().then(res=>{const myVar = {...}})`

```
// a.js
exports.t = (key, lang, props) => {
    return i18next.changeLanguage(lang).then(t => {
        return t(key, props);
    });
};

// b.js
import {t} from './a.js'
const myVar = {
  a: "a",
  b: "b",
  c: (()=>{
     switch (template) {
       case 'a':
         // Promise should return value here from t();
       default:
         break; 
     }
  })(),
  d: (async () => {
     switch (template) {
       case 'a':
         // Not working, returns Promise... Why?
         return await t('email.Registration Confirmation', lng);
       default:
         break; 
     }
  })(),
  e: (()=>{
     switch (template) {
       case 'a':
         // Not working, returns Promise... Why?
         return t('email.Registration Confirmation', lng).then(res => {
           return res;
         });
       default:
         break; 
     }
  })()
}
```

Is it possible at all, that JavaScript waits for that `Promise` to be resolved, and then finishes creating an object?

Comment: `async` functions return promises because they are asynchronous, so they cannot return a value now.

Comment: check my update

Comment: "*The same function here: [,,,] Nicely returns value...*" but...there is no `return` statement there. That code just executes the IIFE and leaves.

Comment: I was also stuck at the same point. And the only solution I got is storing response in state and use it. I don't understand the reason why async is returning a promise.

Comment: I have no state, as this is a pure Node app, no React there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`async` and `await` are tools to **manage** promises by letting you use syntax that appears to be non-asynchronous inside an `async` function.

Consequently, an `async` function will **always** return a promise (which will resolve to whatever the return value is when all the promises inside it have resolved).

---

You are wrong about the function after `case 'Register':`. It returns a promise. You have no code to examine what it returns though.

Comment: How then should i rewrite the const from so it returns value, keeping in mind, that t() is Promise itself? t().then() ?

Comment: You can access it in a callback passed to `then` like any promise. You can't return it outside it though, because it will be too late.

Comment: Tried with then(), now i get "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined", which is super confusing as i have: "import { t } from '../i18next';"

Comment: The `t` function has no return statement.

Comment: I have tried everything i know with returns, thens, etc, and i still can not get a value... It's always Promise in return. I have reformatted my question, could you please guide me, what am i missing?

Comment: You can't stop async operations from being async. A promise object is a promise that there will be data in the future. You can't replace the promise with the data from the future because time travel isn't possible.

Comment: Basically that means, that such approach is not possible at all? How then it is possible to get the t() value? Which construction should i use?

Comment: You call `then()` (which will trigger the callback when the value arraives) and *use the value inside the callback*.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is what i was afraid of :(