# Get results of fetch in react functional component

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-functional-component

So I have this react component that calls out using a `fetch` and then should retrieve the results of that API call and then use those in my functional component. But for some reason it's not getting the results (json), but instead just setting it equal to the Promise itself.

My component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { fetchGames } from './fetchGames'

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({games: []})
  const games = fetchGames()

  useEffect(() => {
    setState({ 
      games: games
    })
  }, [])

  return <div data-testid="games">{JSON.stringify(state.games)}</div>
}
```

fetchGames.js

```
export const fetchGames = () => {

    return fetch(`https://${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/games`, this.apiOptions)
        .then(response => {
        return response.json()
        })
}
```

I have tried setting the fetchGames function to be async and awaiting the fetch inside, but that didn't seem to work.

In my component, the `const games` is a Promise whereas it should be an array.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting Promise instead of a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838833/why-am-i-getting-promise-instead-of-a-value)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `await` async methods, or use the `then` callback.

So

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({games: []})
  

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchGames().then(games => setState({ 
      games: games
    }));
    
  }, [])

  return <div data-testid="games">{JSON.stringify(state.games)}</div>
}
```

or

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({games: []})
  

  useEffect(() => {
    async function setupGames(){
       const games = await fetchGames();
       setState({ 
         games: games
       });
    }
    setupGames();
  }, [])

  return <div data-testid="games">{JSON.stringify(state.games)}</div>
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to always ensure `fetchGames` returns a value rather than a promise?

Comment: @Ryanhipkiss no. Since you use fetch, and fetch is asynchronous, you will have to either use the `async/await` approach or use the `then` callbacks.

Comment: I do use `then` within the `fetchGames` function though? I thought that would return the value?

Comment: @Ryanhipkiss if you read the docs of [`Response.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) you will see that it also returns a promise. (*just as [`Promise.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) does*)